# Is the word "school" in the phrase "school of thoughts" a collective noun?

Tags: nouns, collective-nouns

I know "school" in the phrase "school of fish" is a collective noun. Is it a collective noun in "school of thoughts" as well?

Comment: What is a "school of thoughts"?

Comment: Hello, Sreesanth. The phrase you have in mind is "school of thought," I believe.

Answer (score 3):

No, a *school of thought* (singular *thought*) is a particular line of thinking, unified by style or approach.  From *[Forced Justice: School Desegregation and the Law](https://books.google.com/books?id=BJuAZpULzAsC&pg=PA180&dq=%22school%20of%20thought%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBTgKahUKEwiu5eig9ozJAhXBHD4KHRvnANQ#v=onepage&q=%22school%20of%20thought%22&f=false)* by D J Armor:

> One **school of thought** maintains that mandatory techniques are most
>   effective for student desegregation, which is generally defined as
>   racial balance and measured by the index of dissimilarity.

That is, one way of thinking was that mandatory rules would solve segregation in the US.  The opposing **school of thought** espoused voluntary programs.